# How do I mark a call as completed once I transfer it to another number using Twilio API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-twiml

The code below intercepts a call in progress and transfer the call to a new number (This piece works as expected).
The question is:

1. Should I mark the original call as "completed"
2. How do I do this?

```
    $call_sid = $_SESSION['CallSid'];
    $sid    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $token  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $twilio = new \Twilio\Rest\Client($sid, $token);

    $call = $twilio->calls($call_sid)->update(['twiml' => '<Response><Say>Redirecting to Buba</Say><Dial callerId="+18888880592">+14888068886</Dial></Response>']);
    //TODO cancel this CALL SID. Status=completed??
    print($call->to);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Twilio call legs are kept up via Twilio Markup Language (TwiML). If you modify one call leg which appears to be what you are doing, if there is another call leg (no conference involved) that is part of that call, that leg will begin processing any TwiML after the `<Dial>` that originally connected the two parties. If there is no TwiML after the `<Dial>`, Twilio will hangup that call leg, so no action required on your side.

You should be able to see this behavior in your call logs.